# selecting from the beginning to a substring of a string in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, substring

if i have a string = "helloiamastring"

and i want to select from the beginning of the string to the "lo". how can i do that?

i thought it would be something along the lines of

```
string[/\A/.."lo"]
```

or `string[/\A/../lo/]`

that would give me "hello". alas it doesn't and i don't know where to look

(i also need to be able to do this without knowing where in the string the "lo" is positioned)

I'm new. I'm sure I've read how to do this somewhere but i can't remember where. any help would be appreciated!

thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would work:

```
"helloiamastring"[/.*lo/]
#=> "hello"
```

If there are multiple occurrences of `lo` and you want to match only the first one, use `/.*?lo/` instead.

Comment: thanks, one more question. what if i wanted to go up to, but not including the "lo"? so an exclusive range. => "hel"

Comment: You can use capture groups and provide the group's index: `"hello"[/(.*)lo/, 1]` returns the first group, i.e. `"hel"`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
string = "helloiamastring"
string[/\A.*[lo]/]
=> "hello"
```

Or if you want it to stop at the first lo you can do this:

```
 string[/\A.*?lo/]
```

Comment: your first regex is wrong: `string = "heliamastring"
;string[/\A.*[lo]/]
=> "hel"`, and the second has too many catches

Comment: And the `/\A/` is redundant.